# Largest integer $k$ such that $\frac{a^{m+1}+b^{m+1}}{a^m+b^m}\geq\sqrt[k]{\frac{a^k+b^k}2}$

Tags: analysis, inequality, optimization, contest-math, rearrangement-inequality

The setup is as follows:

Suppose that $m$ is a given natural number. What is the greatest natural number $k$ such that for all real numbers $a,b>0$, we have $$\sqrt[k]{\frac{a^k+b^k}2}\le\frac{a^{m+1}+b^{m+1}}{a^m+b^m}$$?

*Remark:* Note that $$\sqrt[k]{\frac{a^k+b^k}2}\le\sqrt[l]{\frac{a^l+b^l}2}$$ when $k\le l$ by the [Power mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Inequality_between_any_two_power_means).

**My attempt:** I will show that $k\geq 1$, no matter what $m$ is:

Note that $$(a-b)(a^m-b^m)\geq 0$$ for all $a,b>0$ which implies that  $$ab^m+a^mb \le a^{m+1}+b^{m+1}$$

and thus $$a^{m+1}+ab^m+a^mb+b^{m+1}\le2(a^{m+1}+b^{m+1})$$

i.e.

$$(a^m+b^m)(a+b)\le2(a^{m+1}+b^{m+1})$$

which is exactly the above inequality for $k=1$.

Comment: Please clarify: Title says "smallest" but text says "greatest". You likely want greatest, since the RHS is an increasing function of $k$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you for catching that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint.

Let $a\geq b$ and $a=xb$.

Thus, $x\geq1$ and we need $f(x)\geq0,$ where
$$f(x)=\ln\left(x^{m+1}+1\right)-\ln\left(x^m+1\right)-\frac{1}{k}\ln\left(x^k+1\right)+\frac{\ln2}{k}.$$
Now, $f(1)=f'(1)=0$ and $f''(1)=\frac{2m+1-k}{4},$ which says that for $k>2m+1$ our inequality is wrong.

Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{x^{m+1}+1}{x^m+1}\geq\sqrt[2m+1]{\frac{x^{2m+1}+1}{2}},$$ which is smooth:  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1750157